# как распарсить вложенную sql таблицу

Tags: sql

есть вложенная таблица "teacherslessons" содержащая в себе поля
'id'
'teacher'(содержит в себе id из таблицы "teachers")
'lesson'(содержит в себе id из таблицы "lessons").
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно распарсить таблицу, чтобы получить не айдишники элементов, а их значения[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [песочнице](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f7b4f/2) я создал для вас две таблицы teacherslessons и teachers и связал их. По моему образцу можете сделать тоже связь с таблицей lessons.

И можете почитать тут про связи [таблиц](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).